# Java TCPSocket breaks after Client closes connection

Tags: java, tcp

I am very new to programming, especially to socket programming. I tried to figure out how communication works in real (not in all my books), but ran immediately into my first problem with the downloaded SimpleEchoServer example. Communicationflow works but when the Clientsocket closes his connection without sending a specific string, my serversocket breaks down. Can you please tell what have i've done wrong?

This is the server side:

```
import java.net.*; 
import java.io.*; 
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class EchoServer { 

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 

    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    Integer port = new Integer(args[0]);

    try { 

        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port); 

        } 

    catch (IOException e) { 

            System.err.println("Could not listen on port: "+port); 
            System.exit(1); 

        } 

    Socket clientSocket = null; 
    System.out.println ("Waiting for connection on port "+port+" ...");

    try { 

        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); 

        }

    catch (IOException e) { 

            System.err.println("Accept failed."); 
            System.exit(1);

        } 

    System.out.println ("Connection successful");
    System.out.println ("Waiting for input.....");

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true); 
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")); 

    String inputLine; 

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) { 

        System.out.println ("received: " + inputLine); 
        out.println(inputLine); 

        if (inputLine.equals("Bye.")) 
        break; 

    } 

    out.close(); 
    in.close(); 
    clientSocket.close(); 
    serverSocket.close(); 

   } 

}
```

and that's the client side

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class EchoClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String serverHostname = new String (args[0]);
    Integer port = new Integer(args[1]);

    if (args.length > 0)

        serverHostname = args[0];
        System.out.println ("Attemping to connect to host " + serverHostname + " on port 10007.");

        Socket echoSocket = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;

        try {

            echoSocket = new Socket(serverHostname, port);
            out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

                System.err.println("Don't know about host: " + serverHostname);
                System.exit(1);

            } catch (IOException e) {

                System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for " + "the connection to: " + serverHostname);
                System.exit(1);

            }

       BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
       String userInput;

     System.out.print ("input: ");

     while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {

           out.println(userInput);
           System.out.println("echo: " + in.readLine());
         System.out.print ("input: ");

       }

       out.close();
       in.close();
       stdIn.close();
       echoSocket.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: The problem you are facing is very similar to the one described here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387210/java-closing-client-socket-resets-server-socket/28387292#comment45112177_28387292

Comment: Thanks i will read this now. first i want to say i also tried the multithreaded echoserver ant that breaks after 3 requests. the first is accepted, the secont freezes my serverconsole and the third breaks the connection with a socket - reset message in client console

Comment: I will add this as an answer then.

Comment: This is not an abort. Both sides are closing the connection in the normal way. 'Breaks down' is not a problem description. Tell us what actually happens. Exception? Stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the ServerSocket that breaks.

The EchoServer reads from the client socket's InputStream in the loop `while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)`. When the socket connection is terminated, attempting to read will throw an exception. Since the loop isn't inside a try-catch-block, the exception kills the server process.

To prevent that, you need to handle the exception.

```
try {
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) { 

        System.out.println ("received: " + inputLine); 
        out.println(inputLine); 

        if (inputLine.equals("Bye.")) 
            break; 

    } 
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("Connection error... terminating.");
}
```

Comment: What `IOException` would that be? There's nothing in this code that would case that loop not to terminate normally.

Comment: This one: Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)[...]. I think this is only a problem when the socket connection is not being closed properly, for example by simply killing the EchoClient. The code runs fine when Socket.close() is called in the client's loop.